# Visualize multiple websites' Google Analytics data

Tags: analytics

Is there a way I can quickly see key Google Analytics 4 website stats for many websites at once, perhaps in spreadsheet form?

Answer (score 1):

You could try **[Looker Studio](https://lookerstudio.google.com/)** or the **[Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)**

### [Visualize your Analytics data in Looker Studio](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9849873?hl=en)

> #### See your data in an interactive, customizable and sharable dashboard.
>
> Looker Studio turns your data into informative, easy to read, easy to share, and fully customizable dashboards and reports. With Looker Studio you can:
>
> - **Easily connect** to a variety of data sources.
> - **Visualize your data** through highly configurable charts and >- tables.
> - **Share** your insights with your team or with the world.
> - **Collaborate** on reports with your team.
> - **Speed up** your report creation process with built-in sample reports.

### [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)

> The Google Analytics spreadsheet add-on brings you the power of the Google Analytics API combined with the power of data manipulation in Google Spreadsheets. With this tool, you can:
>
> - Query and report data from multiple views.
> - Compute and display custom calculations.
> - Create visualizations and embed those visualizations on third-party websites.
> - Schedule your reports to run and update automatically.
> - Control who can see your data and visualizations by using Google Sheets' sharing and privacy features.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).